# ScrollBar on DataGrid keeps jumping back to the top

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, scrollbar, position

I am working with a WPF MVVM solution where I have a grid that is being updated multiple times every second.  I need to allow the user the ability to scroll halfway down the grid and to remain there in between grid data updates.  Right now if I scroll down the grid, the scrollbar position will jump back to the top as soon as the next time the grid's data is updated.

How can I accomplish keeping the x position of my scrollbar in its current location even when updates are processed.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you replacing/resetting the collection the datagrid is bound to in your updates or are you modifying the collection?  I believe the grid  will reset if you do something like myCollection = UpdatedCollection as opposed to modifying your collection using myCollection.Add(x) and myCollection.Remove(x)

Comment: Why would I want to Add or Remove items to my collection manually?  As I stated this dataSet is updated multiple times per second.

Comment: Still, your dataset could be updated by invoking the Add/Remove methods of the collection. Are you binding your Grid's ItemSource property to an ObservableCollection? If so, modifying the collection through Add/Remove would be the best solution. However, if you reassign the Grid's ItemsSource like `Grid.ItemSource = new List()` your Grid will be reset everytime, probably losing the scrollposition in the process

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"/>
```

will should resolve this problem.
The reason is normally that the ListView always goes to the last selected element.
Also you need to make sure that the list is being populated by binding.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the scrollbar position:

```cs
private void Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(DataGridControlName, 0);
    _scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
}

// save
_scrollViewerVOffset = _scrollViewer?.VerticalOffset ?? 0;
// restore
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _scrollViewer?.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_scrollViewerVOffset));
```